# how to filter object of arrays based on inner object column condition

Tags: javascript

I have the following object and i want to only get the first row that is row with Number (rowNumber: 1)
The criteria is that "columnId": *8505590182897540* should have its *value* equal to **Open** and "columnId": *7009559238731652* should have its *value* not exist.

```
  output =  { "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1844195940165508,
            "rowNumber": 1,

            "cells": [
                {
                    "columnId": 8505590182897540,
                    "value": "Open",
                    "displayValue": "Open"
                },
                {
                    "columnId": 7009559238731699,
                    "value": "Steep",
                    "displayValue": "Steep"
                },
                {
                    "columnId": 7009559238731652
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1844195940165509,
            "rowNumber": 2,

            "cells": [
                {
                    "columnId": 8505590182897540,
                    "value": "Open",
                    "displayValue": "Open"
                },
                {
                    "columnId": 7009559238731699,
                    "value": "Steep",
                    "displayValue": "Steep"
                },
                {
                    "columnId": 7009559238731652,
                    "value": "Field has value",
                    "displayValue": "Field has value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to loop through the rows with the following code and filter based on the cell.value = Open" and add the result to a list, but how can i check for each cell based on the columnid '8505590182897540' if the value =="Open" and the columnid '7009559238731652' where value is blank and add that row id to the list?

this is the code i have so far

```
var emptyArray = [];
output.rows.map(function (row) {
    row.cells.forEach(function (cell) {
          if (cell.value == 'Open') {
              emptyArray.push(row.id);
          }
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define filters for cell objects and check all filters.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1844195940165508, rowNumber: 1, cells: [{ columnId: 8505590182897540, value: "Open", displayValue: "Open" }, { columnId: 7009559238731699, value: "Steep", displayValue: "Steep" }, { columnId: 7009559238731652 }] }, { id: 1844195940165509, rowNumber: 2, cells: [{ columnId: 8505590182897540, value: "Open", displayValue: "Open" }, { columnId: 7009559238731699, value: "Steep", displayValue: "Steep" }, { columnId: 7009559238731652, value: "Field has value", displayValue: "Field has value" }] }],
    filters = [
        { columnId: 8505590182897540, value: 'Open' },
        { columnId: 7009559238731652, value: undefined }
    ],
    result = data.filter(({ cells }) => filters.every(f => cells.some(c =>
        c.columnId === f.columnId &&
        c.value === f.value
    )));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the rows, within the map lambda [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the desired cells. Something like:

```js
const filterCells = v => 
  v.columnId === 8505590182897540 && v.value === `Open` ||
  v.columnId === 7009559238731652 && !v.value;
const filtered = values().rows.map(v => 
  ( {id: v.id, cellsFound: v.cells.filter(filterCells)} ));

console.log(`if you only need ids: ${filtered.map(v => v.id)}`);
console.log(filtered);

function values() {
  return {
    "rows": [{
        "id": 1844195940165508,
        "rowNumber": 1,

        "cells": [{
            "columnId": 8505590182897540,
            "value": "Open",
            "displayValue": "Open"
          },
          {
            "columnId": 7009559238731699,
            "value": "Steep",
            "displayValue": "Steep"
          },
          {
            "columnId": 7009559238731652
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1844195940165509,
        "rowNumber": 2,

        "cells": [{
            "columnId": 8505590182897540,
            "value": "Open",
            "displayValue": "Open"
          },
          {
            "columnId": 7009559238731699,
            "value": "Steep",
            "displayValue": "Steep"
          },
          {
            "columnId": 7009559238731652,
            "value": "Field has value",
            "displayValue": "Field has value"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```